# gulp-concat seems to be doing nothing

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I am attempting to concat a few javascript files as part of my gulp build. I am following the "documentation" as much as possible, but there aren't many answers there. Here are the commands I am using.

```
gulp.task('concatMe', function ()
{
    console.log('I am in the concat function.');
    return gulp.src(['/app/core/threejs/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('new.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

I would think that this takes all of the javascript files in the folder targeted and concatenates them in the new.js file at the desired directory.

While the console log works, nothing is actually done.

How do I know if it found the files I want?
How should the base URL be specified? 
How should the destination URL be specified? 
Does the destination file and folder need to already exist or will the code create it?

Thanks

Comment: Why is your source   (['/app/core/threejs/*.js'])  in brackets?  I suggest removing them and changing it to './app/core/threejs/*.js'  <== note the initial dot.  The base url is taken from the first passed in file as per the docs.  The destination folder and files will be created for you if necessary.  Finally, is your gulpfile at the root of your .src call?

Comment: In addition to Mark's comments, you can add a call to `.pipe(print())` before the concat() call to see what is actually included in the src() call. I suspect, like Mark, that the problem lies there.

Answer (score 0):

In your gulp file, have you included the below line?

```
var plugin = require("gulp-load-plugins")();
```

Then you need to modify your code to:

```
  return gulp.src(['/app/core/threejs/*.js'])
    .pipe(plugin.concat('new.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
```

Hope this helps